Error Protobuf on schema registry kafka with masstransit
Im trying to produce message to Kafka in Protobuf format for this im using schema registry
   rider.AddProducer<SMSResult>(options.TopicResponse, (context, cfg) 
        => cfg.SetValueSerializer(new ProtobufSerializer<SMSResult>(schemaRegistryClient).AsSyncOverAsync()));

and this my proto file that i generated a SMSResult from:
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "SMSResultGrpc";

package sms_callback;

message SmsPartDetail {
  string Content = 1;
  bool IsSent = 2;
  bool IsPending = 3; 
}

message SMSResult {
  string Id = 1;
  repeated SmsPartDetail SmsParts = 2;
  string Phone = 3;
  string Text = 4;
  SmsProvider Provider = 5;
  string Status = 6;
  google.protobuf.StringValue Process = 7;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp CreatedOn = 8;
  google.protobuf.StringValue Error = 9;
  string CallbackUrl = 10;          
}

Now when i`m trying to consume this message i receive following exception
09:52:45] [ERR] [] R-FAULT loopback://localhost/kafka/online-crm-sms-response-dev 01000000-0cf8-9ed9-9854-08dcccae2dfe 00:00:00.0239704
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: google/protobuf/empty.proto
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.ProtobufUtils.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Parse>b__0(KeyValuePair`2 x)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.ProtobufUtils.Parse(String schema, IDictionary`2 imports)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.ProtobufDeserializer`1.ParseSchema(Schema schema)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.AsyncSerde`1.GetParsedSchema(Schema schema)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.AsyncSerde`1.GetSchema(String subject, Int32 writerId, String format)
   at Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.ProtobufDeserializer`1.DeserializeAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 data, Boolean isNull, SerializationContext context)

as i see in schema registry list, its already added
 google/protobuf/empty.proto;
 google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
 google/protobuf/timestamp.proto

and its trying to add them again.
How can i solve it? because i really need this imports in my proto because some of properties should be nullable and one of them need to be datetime format.
Can i write something in configuration so masstransit would not add the schema registry from the start and i can put the schema without imports?
Also if i drop schema registry at all it will be good, because i dont need to validate it, i just want to use the Protobuf format for kafka message.

gRPC is a protocol, not a format (it supports other formats than Protobuf). Please share your consumer config. The error comes from the deserializer not the producer

k.TopicEndpoint(options.TopicResponse,
options.ConsumerGroupId, e =>
{
e.SetValueDeserializer(new ProtobufDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient).AsSyncOverAsync());
e.ConfigureConsumer(context);
e.UseMessageRetry(r =>
r.Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100)));
});

btw, i have another proto file in this project that also importing same imports, could it be the problem?

I don't think files matter; it's how the record is being serialized. I'm not familiar with the Kafka .NET client options
